# how can I avoid Invalid in Data Validation

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have two dependent drop down, each cell have deferent options like picture 1,2.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DL23T.png),[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LPY00.png) but whenever I change option in cell 1, cell 2 will show invalid
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jdSMT.png),

how can i avoid this error, or al least when I choose option in cell 1, cell 2 will auto choose option belong to cell 1.
Thank you.

Comment: `how can i avoid this error,` When you change Option 1, the script needs to test whether option 2 is a valid option; if "yes", then do nothing, if "no", then delete option 2.

Comment: but how can I do it, bro? any script for me, thank you so much

Comment: Would you please describe how your dynamic dependant drop downs work?